# How to set percentage value by default on each bars in horizontal bar chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have used horizontal bar chart from *chart.js* where i need percentage values to be shown next to each bar at right side? here is the bar sample image.

[click here to view sample image of bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToRYk.png)

Also these are the options i have tried :

```
xAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100
              },
              grid: {
              offset: false
            }
            },
          ],
          yAxes: [
            {
              gridLines: {
                display: false,
              },
              display: "right",
              barPercentage: 0.8,
              minBarLength: 2,
            },
          ],
```

Is there any option which can turn the percentage values on at he right side of the horizontal bar chart?
Please click below image to see the expected output
[click image expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrHTP.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the datalabels plugin

Example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0-rc"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="850" height="520"></canvas>
<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
  Chart.defaults.set('plugins.datalabels', {
    color: '#FE777B'
  });
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        label: 'Advisor Closed MTD',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(192,111,94)',
        barThickness: 25,
        datalabels: {
          color: '#FFCE56'
        }

      }],
    },
    options: {
      indexAxis: 'y',
      responsive: false,
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          formatter: (val, context) => (`${val}%`),
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'end',
          labels: {
            value: {
              color: 'blue'
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Percentages are already coming at the end without installing any other plugin but on 100% the text getting cut

Comment: Care to share all your code then, because with your current yAxes no percentages show on the bars as you want, also I dont see the percentages being cut off

Comment: If at 100% the text gets cut off does that mean that your graph goes to the edge of the canvas? If so then you want to make the canvas bigger. If not then share your code.